# How to keep div inside container frames using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple (i think) question?

I have a conatainer 800x400 and inside is a div 10x10.
The div inside is moving by pressing the arrow keys ,but what i like to do is
keep the div inside the frames of container.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  go_kw();

});

function go_kw() {
  move_me();
}


function move_me() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function (event) {

    let key = event.which;
    let qt = $('#qw');

    if(key == 37){
      qt.css('left', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 38){
      qt.css('top', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 39){
      qt.css('left', '+=1');
    }else if(key == 40){
      qt.css('top', '+=1');
    }



  });
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
#qw {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="qw"></div>
</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my goal is to do this as simple it can be done.

greetz!

Comment: Have you attempted to achieve this yourself? It's always good to see some attempts, even if they don't work!

Comment: Yes i try i'm acctually learn javascript and my problem was that i understand the logic for what i would like to do but have a problem with translate it for the code :D also I was curious what possibilities are available thanks for respons :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.max (which selects the highest value of two arguments) and Math.min (which does the opposite), like so (for horizontal movement):

```
if(key == 37){
    qt.css('left', Math.max(qt.css('left') - 1, 0));
}
else if(key == 39){
    qt.css('left', Math.min(qt.css('left') + 1, 800));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that you are not past your div borders before moving `parseInt(qt.css('left')) > 0`

Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  go_kw();

});

function go_kw() {
  move_me();
}


function move_me() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function (event) {

    let key = event.which;
    let qt = $('#qw');

    if(key == 37 && parseInt(qt.css('left')) > 0){
      qt.css('left', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 38 && parseInt(qt.css('top')) > 0){
      qt.css('top', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 39 && parseInt(qt.css('left')) < 790){
      qt.css('left', '+=1');
    }else if(key == 40 && parseInt(qt.css('top')) < 390){
      qt.css('top', '+=1');
    }



  });
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
#qw {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="qw"></div>
</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way should be to test if your positions are superior than 0 for left and top and lower than `#container` width and height for respectively right and bottom.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  go_kw();

});

function go_kw() {
  move_me();
}


function move_me() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function (event) {
    
    let key = event.which;
    let qt = $('#qw');

    let maxHeight = $('#container').height();
    let maxWidth = $('#container').width();

    if(key == 37 && qt.position().left > 0){
      qt.css('left', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 38 && qt.position().top > 0){
      qt.css('top', '-=1');
    }else if(key == 39 && qt.position().left < maxWidth){
      qt.css('left', '+=1');
    }else if(key == 40 && qt.position().left < maxHeight){
      qt.css('top', '+=1');
    }



  });
}
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
#qw {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div id="qw"></div>
</div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a field with a value for left and top and check it during change like so (I've made the container smaller for easier testing, can be enlarged in css):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  go_kw();

});

function go_kw() {
  move_me();
}

var qwWidth = $('#qw').width();
var qwHeight = $('#qw').height();
var maxLeft = $('#container').width() - qwWidth;
var maxTop = $('#container').height() - qwHeight;

var currentPos = {
  left: 0,
  top: 0
};

function move_me() {
  $(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    let key = event.which;

    if (key == 37) {
      changePos('left', -1, maxLeft);
    } else if (key == 38) {
      changePos('top', -1, maxTop);
    } else if (key == 39) {
      changePos('left', 1, maxLeft);
    } else if (key == 40) {
      changePos('top', 1, maxTop);
    }

    $('#qw').css(currentPos);
  });
}

function changePos(prop, changeVal, maxVal) {
  var newVal = currentPos[prop] + changeVal;

  if (newVal < 0) {
    currentPos[prop] = 0;
  } else if (newVal > maxVal) {
    currentPos[prop] = maxVal;
  } else {
    currentPos[prop] = newVal;
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#qw {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="qw"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```